# trouble understanding Obj-C MVC: exit and unwindSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

Created a button to exit from a second ViewController to the previous ViewController. I've read in tutorials that this should be by using the "EXIT" in the view controller. (control+click+drag the button to EXIT).

I have created an "exit" button on this second controller, and a method on the ViewController class to hook up with the control+click+drag exit segue. This method is completely empty:

```
 - (IBAction) unwindToMainMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *) unwindSegue
{

}
```

And yet, when I press the button it returns back to the previous ViewController as I intended, but I was expecting nothing should happen (as the method has no content).

I assume the StoryboardSegue object passed into this method is this EXIT that I dragged the button into, but there's no code to handle that object.

EDIT:
Also, I am not returning anything, yet the declaration of the method says it should return an IBAction. Why is the compiler not complaining?

Can you help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: Did you have a look at ["Technical Note TN2298 – Using Unwind Segues"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/) which describes all the gory details?

Comment: I've just started looking into Obj-c and still getting used to the apple docs. Thank you for the link - that is a good find. Will take me a while to digest through this. If I'm reading it correctly, this method I created is an extra action before the segue is executed. Still, shouldn't this have failed to compile? I'm not returning anything on my newly created method :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow,

Firstly, IBAction is just a way to say 'you can drag to this' for Xcode, it's not really like a return type, i just consider it void.

Secondly, it is working as intended :D Basically you can now call this method like you have with hooking it up with the storyboard or you can manually call it like:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToMainMenu" sender:self];
```

and all of the variables that you have set in your current view controller will be passed back to the source view controller that you're unwinding to.

e.g

```
-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindToMainMenu"]) {
    VcExample *vcExample= (VcExample *)segue.sourceViewController;
    NSString *string = vcExample.aVariableNameYoureInterestedInFromTheVCYouUnwoundFromLolThisIsLong;
    }  
}
```

The unwind segue is just a built in feature, if you hook that button up to it,  it will segue

Comment: Thank you Ben! :)
That makes sense and really makes it clear. Just to see if I understood the "You can drag to this". The IBAction is actually void, and XCode uses it as flag or an handle for the interactive storyboard builder, as if it was an overload for the return type?

Comment: Yeah, correct. I had a little look before I wrote it to make sure but i was right, void and IBAction are totally identical other than the builder interactivity. You could even use IBAction instead of returning void in methods and it wouldn't make any difference as it's not hooked up to anything. Xcode is really good, I enjoyed learning it as I started on Android. Enjoy buddy :)